# Active to passive voice conversion and vice versa

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

I have to convert the following sentences from active to passive voice and vice versa:

A) *Most insomnia is caused by stress.*

B) *Health chiefs have voiced concerns that Britain is fast becoming a nation of sleeping pill addicts.*

I think that the conversions are:

A) *Stress causes most insomnia.*

B) *Concerns that Britain is fast becoming a nation of sleeping pill addicts have been voiced by health chiefs.*

My questions:

A) Are my conversions correct?

B) This "most" on sentence A causes problems to me. Specifically, I think that the way I have written sentence A doesn't make any sense as far as "most" is concerned.

C) Can I rephrase my conversions so that minimum reordering of phrases is present and if yes, how? (you can see that I have completely changed the ordering of certain phrases on the sentences)

D) The "is becoming" verb on sentence B can't be converted, right?

Comment: Where did the "anxiety" come from in A? What is your concern about "most"? Why do you want to 'convert' "is fast becoming"?

Comment: @Trevord Error on A copy pasting... Sorry. Will correct that. Also, can an admin migrate this question to the site you suggested, whose existence I wasn't aware of. I don't ask for proof-reading. My main concerns are my other questions.

Comment: I don't know what the process is for migrating Qs, but I've raised a flag to the mods for you.

Comment: @Trevord Here most is being used as "usually", which is quite weird for me, since on my converted sentence "most" could also mean that the main reason of insomnia is stress, which isn't the purpose, because here it means eg that 80% of all cases of insomnia are due to stress.

Comment: Well, the exercise requests full conversion and I was wondering whether I am required to find a synonym for "is fast becoming" so as to change the voice and alter the wording.

Comment: 1. I read "most" as meaning "most"! I can't comment on whether you should be 're-interpreting' the terminology. 2. I also can't answer to what extent your exercise requires you amend the wording.  I'll leave it there.

Comment: C) One of the stylistic benefits of voice changes is the reordering of the elements of a sentence, say, to emphasize the more important by placing it first. D) *become* isn't transitive, so you're right.  The clue is that you can't specify an agent in a prepositional phrase with *by*.

Comment: @deadrat Actually, old bean, we  normally passivise for emphasis to make the thing at the *end* more prominent, not the thing at the beginning. It's all about the end!

Comment: @Araucaria It's not always about the end.  If the story is about the mayor, we transform *The voters elected the mayor to another four-tear term* to *The **mayor** was elected to another four-year term*.

Comment: @deadrat Right.  So if the story is about the mayor, the mayor is the least interesting and emphatic thing about any new sentence about the mayor. The new sexy info about the mayor topic, the stuff we didn't already know, or talk about, is shunted to the end. (cont)

Comment: @deadrat But more importantly, we're probably using a passive there to get rid of the even more boring agent, *the voters*. This isn't the same thing as trying to make the boring old mayor more prominent. [I wrote a bit here, which contains some of the modern conventional academic wisdom on why we use passives](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328050/whats-the-reason-for-using-the-passive-voice/328091#328091). Of course, that's just the conventional academic wisdom. It doesn't mean it's right!

Comment: @deadrat Information packaging stuff is mostly about shunting new information to the end of a clause and boring old topics already mentioned to the beginning. There's some really good books about it. I'll try and get some good refs to you if you're interested (I hope you don't think I'm implying you're a grammar anorak like me).

Comment: @Araucaria We are? The four-year term is at the end of both sentences. It might or might not be "sexy."  The focus of the sentence is either the voters or the mayor.  Ordinarily we don't focus on voters, who are assumed to be present in the verb *to elect*.  But that might not be true if say, we're talking about the fascist, nativist, ignorant nihilists who've taken over a major US political party.

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, I'd like the references.  First time that I've seen *anorak* used in this slang sense, but I can't be a grammar anorak like you.  You actually know what you're talking about. I am a grammar anorak manqué. More comments, including my traditional nitpicking, over at the jump.

Comment: @deadrat I think anorak derives from our hackneyed view of trainspotters, who will go out in all weathers and stand around for hours in the rain waiting to see some train they haven't seen before. So us Brits usually use the term for amateurs/enthusiasts/pros who are slightly obsessive, especially if the subject matter/hobby at hand is perceived by other people as rather dull.

Comment: @deadrat Re references, I'll append some more later, but for the time being there's [this paper by Betty Birner](http://www.zas.gwz-berlin.de/fileadmin/material/ZASPiL_Volltexte/zp35/zaspil35-birner.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the Original Poster's passive voice sentences are perfectly grammatical. However, b) is slightly awkward in English:

- [Concerns that Britain is fast becoming a nation of sleeping pill addicts] have been voiced by health chiefs.

The problem here is that the head noun *concerns* takes a declarative content clause as Complement:

- that Britain is fast becoming a nation of sleeping pill addicts

This clause is very long and it makes the Subject very heavy (*heavy* is just a technical term for *very long*). Usually in this kind of situation we tend to move any Complements or Postmodifiers in the noun phrase to the end of the clause. This is called 'extraposition from noun phrase movement'. This makes the sentence easier to process and also makes that information that appears at the end of the sentence more prominent. If we do this with the Original Poster's example we get:

- [Concerns] have been voiced by health chiefs [that Britain is becoming a nation of sleeping pill addicts].

Answer (score 0):

A )Stress causes the most insomnia. (superlative )

b  )Concerns have been voiced by health chiefs that Britain is becoming a nation of sleeping pill addicts.